# Update from TFS 2015 to TFS 2018 SP1 - Error during msbuild

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, msbuild-task

We have updated our TFS 2015 to TFS 2018 SP.
We tried running our builds after updating the Agents to the current Version with the following error:

> "E:_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.120.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\VstsTaskSdk.psd1"
>   wurde nicht  geladen, da in keinem Modulverzeichnis eine gültige
>   Moduldatei gefunden wurde.

Anybody heard this error before?
Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Did you upgrade your build agents?

Comment: yes i updated it to the current version (new download form the tfs)

Comment: @LuWa How about deploy a new agent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows? Is it working? Which version of VS do you install on your build agent machine?

Comment: The agent works, but the vsbuild task not... i have installed VS2015 and VS2017 (latest version).

Comment: @LuWa Can other tasks work? Try to clean folder E:_tasks to see whether the issue persists.

Comment: Damn! I found the solution. I configured the workingfolder to E: instead of E:\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. 
I configured my Agent with the workingfolder to E: instead of E:\
The missing \ was the problem.